# -[UIImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:] randomly becomes tile images

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

The message bubble was a 91pt * 29pt PNG. The UIImageView was in a UITableViewCell. In the attached image, the cell was the first one but it could happen at other index paths. I have not seen a bubble stretched horizontally and tiled vertically.

[image: Sample]

```
// init
UIImage *inMessageBubbleImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"InMessageBubble.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(22, 10, 29-23, 91-85)];
mMessageBubbleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:inMessageBubbleImage];
mMessageBubbleView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self.contentView addSubview:mMessageBubbleView];

// called method later
[mMessageBubbleView addSubview:mTextView];
mMessageBubbleView.frame = frame;
UIImage *messageBubbleImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"InMessageBubble.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(22, 10, 29-23, 91-85)];
[mMessageBubbleView setImage:messageBubbleImage];
```

Comment: Where do you do the "addsubview" exactly?

Comment: In init and after setting the message data